# A Stage of Jenkins shows NaNy NaNd instead the time

Tags: selenium, jenkins

For a declarative Jenkins pipeline, 2 of the 3 stages show the elapsed time, but in the last stage (stage 3) it shows `NaNy` and `NaNd`. I have attached a screenshot showing the issue.

I ran this 3 times, and it repeatedly shows the NaNy and NaNd.

[image]

Comment: `NaN` means [Not A Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN). It's appending that to `y` (I'm assuming for years) and `d` (I'm assuming for days) but I have no idea why. It's pulling a datetime from somewhere and getting null or otherwise bad values and just printing them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jenkins has some related issues, mainly https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-48881 (which is not resolved yet).